# Impersonate user for SQL connection strings c# MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, connection-string, impersonation

I have couple of connection strings in web.config, ideally using those connection strings  and the credentials specified (in web.config) I will have to open a connection and do an insert - for both the connections (lets says connection1 and connection 2).

Now connetcion1 and connection2 have different credentials. I have tried using them in the connection string of web.config but it always says login failed for user. Below are the connection strings.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="connection_2" connectionString="Data Source=domain\servername;Initial Catalog=DBName;User ID=domain\xxxx;Password=abcgdd****;"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

<add name="connection_3" connectionString="Data Source=domain\servername;Initial Catalog=DBName;User ID=domain\yyyy;Password=fgdd****;"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
<connectionStrings>
```

So after some googling understood that I have to use impersonation.

Using the below code for impersonation

``````
using (new Impersonator("username","domain","pwd"))
{
// trying to open connection 1 from web.config but it says no such user. 

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Connection1FromConfig"))
                            {
                                cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from abc", connection);
                                connection.Open();
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                connection.Close();
                                
                            }
}

Connection used while impersonation is :

 <add name="Connection2" connectionString="Data Source=domain\server;Initial Catalog=DB;"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

`````

Used the code from here for impersonation class - https://daoudisamir.com/impersonate-users-in-c/
``````

Comment: for impersonation of a domain user to work, the machine running the Impersonator must be a member of the domain, and the user under which the process runs should also be either a domain member or else the computer account -- i.e. if in IIS run the app pool under app pool identity or network_service

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide `Trusted_Connection=yes;` in your connection string if you intend to use Windows Credentials with impersonate.

This is my connectionString that I used successfully,

```
string srvConnection = $"Server={serverName}; Trusted_Connection=yes; connection timeout=15";
```

I got the Impersonator class [from here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10090/A-small-C-Class-for-impersonating-a-User) and was able to use it successfully. SQL account I needed to use was different than the domain account being used with IIS / app pool.

```
string srvConnection = $"Server={ListenerName}; Trusted_Connection=yes; connection timeout=15";
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(srvConnection)) 
{
    using (new Impersonator(creds.Username.Split('\\').Last(), creds.Username.Split('\\').First(), creds.Password))
        connection.Open();

    // other code that needs to use the connection goes here.
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from abc", connection);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

You dont need to close the connection because of the `using` statement. Since impersonation is only required to open the connection, you dont need to use it anywhere other than with `connection.Open();` statement.